# Win7 (x64) - Python error - "ImportError: No module named lxml"

Tags: python, windows-7, lxml, importerror

I'm fairly new to python, but can't seem to get my head around this error - have found posts with similar issues, but none of the responses have helped.

I'm running Python 3.4.0 and have installed a module called lxml.

I wrote some code which starts

```
    from lxml import html
```

This runs perfectly well from the python.exe interface, and the module can be used to succesfully import and parse XML.

However, if I save the script as a *.py file, and try to call it from a cmd.exe prompt, I get the `ImportError: No module named lxml` error.

Python is within C:\Python34, and the relevant module is located in `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\lxml`, which contains the required `__init__.py`
file.

I've checked `sys.path` which, amongst others, holds `C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages`

The double-backslashes and lowercase 'l' in 'lib' shouldn't make a difference, should it? All listed paths appear to have double-backslashes instead of single.
I did attempt to add the path with an uppercase 'L' using

```
    sys.path.insert(1, 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages')
```

which subsequently appeared as a seperate path, however did not resolve the issue.

Additionally, I replaced the first line of my script with

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages')
```

which appeared to attempt to read the required `__init__.py` file (progress!!!), but then gave the following error: `ImportError: Module use of python34.dll conflicts with this version of Python`, so I probably won't pursue this avenue, unless it is of relevance.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with regards to `ImportError: No module named lxml`?

Comment: You are running the code with the wrong interpreter

Comment: @Padraic - thanks, but I don't think that this is the case. When I execute

        'Python'
at the command line, the expected (and correct) version or 3.4.0 is returned.